# Get all IPs associated with a URL, Python

Tags: python

I am trying to find all the IPs that are associated with a URL.  I have been using the package "socket" but am confused by the varying amount of IPs returned with different functions. For example see below. Is there a function to return all the IPs?

```
socket.gethostbyname('google.com')
#returns 1 ip

socket.gethostbyname_ex('google.com')
#returns 6 ips

socket.getaddrinfo('google.com', 80)
#returns 12 ips
```

Is there a function to return all the IPs?

Comment: You'd need to look at a DNS library rather than the socket library. Something like http://www.dnspython.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no function to return "all" IPs. The IP addresses that you see are what your local DNS server knows for `google.com`. These addresses vary from location to location.

All of the methods behave differently, for a reason

- `gethostbyname` returns 1 of the IPv4 addresses in the A records of this host. This is for the simple stuff of "let's just connect any address that is `google.com`".
- `gethostbyname_ex` returns all known IPv4 addresses; that is, all the addresses from A records for `google.com`. This is for the case that you need high availability, so you can try to connect several of these IPv4 addresses and proceed with the connection that succeeds.
- Since neither of the above support IPv6 addresses, `socket.getaddrinfo` returns them as well. Unless you also provide argument `proto=socket.IPPROTO_TCP`, you will have some extra protocols, like same address repeated 3 times - for TCP, UDP and RAW sockets for example.

Of these 3, `socket.getaddrinfo` gives the "most" of the IP addresses, but due to distributed nature of DNS and google's DNS especially, there is no way that you can get them *all*.